# Find the number of unordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{100}$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The original question is:

Find the number of unordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{100}$.

My attempt:

I am able to identify a few solutions, like $x=y=200$ and $x=300$, or $y=150$.
I can't move any forward. Please help.

Comment: Hint : Start with multiplying the equation with $100xy$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233046/number-of-solutions-for-frac1x-frac1y-frac1n-where-1-leq/767623#767623

Comment: Why don't people give askers a chance to figure out something themselves ? I gave a hint, maybe it helps the asker, so why already point out complete answers ?

Comment: @individ, I cannot fully appreciate your method. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Decomposable into factors. It is not difficult.

Comment: @Peter, I have often wondered this, but I *think* it's from a hunger for easy points. Maybe you could ask it on Meta.M.SE?