# Find all positive integers $n$ for which $s(n)=5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

> Question: For each positive integer $n$, let $s(n)$ denote the number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ of positive integers for which $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{n}.$$ Find all positive integers $n$ for which $s(n)=5$.

Solution: Select any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ be such that $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{n}.$$ Next assume that $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, where $p_1,p_2,\cdots, p_k$ are distinct primes and $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\cdots, \alpha_k$ are non-negative integers. Thus $n^2=p_1^{2\alpha_1}p_2^{2\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{2\alpha_k}.$ Hence the total number of positive divisors of $n^2$ is equal to $(2\alpha_1+1)(2\alpha_2+1)\cdots(2\alpha_k+1).$

From the previous equation we have $$n(x+y)=xy\\\implies xy-nx+n^2-ny=n^2\\\implies(x-n)(y-n)=n^2.$$

Now since $x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, implies that $\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y}<\frac{1}{n}$, which in turn implies that $x-n>0$ and $y-n>0$.

Next observe that corresponding to each positive divisor $d$ of $n^2$, we have an unique pair $(x,y)=(d+n,n^2/d+n)$ which is a solution to the equation $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{n}$. We obtain such pairs by solving equations of the form $$\begin{cases} x-n=d \\ y-n=\frac{n^2}{d} ,\end{cases}$$ for each positive divisor $d$ of $n^2$.

Thus, we can conclude that for some $n\in\mathbb{N},$ $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{n},$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{Z^+}\iff (x,y)=(d+n,n^2/d+n)$, for some $d\in \mathbb{Z^+}$, such that $d|n^2$.

Hence, the total number of solutions $(x,y),$ given by $s(n)=(2\alpha_1+1)(2\alpha_2+1)\cdots(2\alpha_k+1).$

Thus, $s(n)=5\iff (2\alpha_1+1)(2\alpha_2+1)\cdots(2\alpha_k+1)=5\iff $exactly one of the $a_i's=2$ and the rest are equal to $0\iff n=p^2,$ for any prime $p$.

Thus, we can finally conclude that $s(n)=5\iff n=p^2,$ for any prime $p$.

Is this solution correct and rigorous enough? And, is there any other way to solve the same?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233046/number-of-solutions-for-frac1x-frac1y-frac1n-where-1-leq/767623#767623

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct, perfectly rigorous, and is indeed the canonical way to solve the question. The key step, of course, is the factorisation into $$(x-n)(y-n)=n^2$$

I don't know of any other ways to do this question; I suspect that any other simple solution which works will be this one in disguise.