# Integers $x$ such that $\frac{nx}{x-n}$ is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to find all solutions of $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{n}$ with $ n < x \leq y \ $ and with a given $n$.

I started manipulating the expression and got $y = \frac{nx}{x-n}$.

For now I'm iterating $x$ from $n+1$ to $2n \ $ (obtained by manipulating $ n < x \leq y $).

So, my question is: How can I generate $x$ such that $\frac{nx}{x-n}$ yields a positive integer, without checking all integers from $n+1$ to $2n$?

(This comes from [project Euler problem 108](https://projecteuler.net/problem=108) that my method manage to solve, but pretty slowly)
I'm pretty new to computer science and all that stuff and don't know yet the tricks of divisibility, so I'm a bit stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Subtracting $n$ from $y$ yields $y-n = \dfrac{n^2}{x-n}$, so you must have $(x-n)|n^2$. It's also easy to check that by adding $n \lt x \le 2n$ this is sufficient.

Comment: As for the number calculating, observe that if $d|n^2$ and $d \le n$, then $\dfrac{n^2}{d}|n^2$ and $\dfrac{n^2}{d}>d$ unless $d=n$. So the number of solution is $\dfrac{d(n^2)+1}{2}$.

Comment: @Zerox Thanks a lot for this, my code already runs 10 times faster, and I think I can improve it even more with what you gave me!

Comment: The easiest solution, though not the only one, is
$\quad n=x\pm1 \quad$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233046/number-of-solutions-for-frac1x-frac1y-frac1n-where-1-leq/767623#767623

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of solutions for $\frac{1}{X} + \frac{1}{Y} = \frac{1}{N!}$ where $1 \leq N \leq 10^6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233046/number-of-solutions-for-frac1x-frac1y-frac1n-where-1-leq)

Comment: Your title asks about "integers" and you used the tag for diophantine equations, but you did not specify in the body of the Question that $x,y$ should be (positive) integers.  Please make it a practice to give a self-contained problem statement in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $x$ and $y$ be integers with $y\geq x>n$ such that
$$\frac1x+\frac1y=\frac1n.$$
Clearing denominators shows that this is equivalent to
$$n(x+y)=xy.$$
Let $d:=\gcd(x,y)$ so that $x=dX$ and $y=dY$ for coprime integers $X$ and $Y$, and
$$n(X+Y)=dXY.$$
Then $X+Y$ is coprime to $X$ and $Y$, so $X+Y$ divides $d$, say $d=c(X+Y)$, and so
$$x=c(X+Y)X,\qquad y=c(X+Y)Y,\qquad n=cXY.$$

Conversely, let $n=cXY$ for any three positive integers $c$, $X$ and $Y$ with $X\leq Y$. Then for $x:=c(X+Y)X$ and $y:=c(X+Y)Y$ you have $n<x\leq y$ and
$$\frac1x+\frac1y=\frac1n.$$
So your problem boils down to factoring $n$.